# Group role based authorization

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, authorization, role-based-access-control

I've been trying to implement a group based authorization.
I have gone ahead and implemented the user based authorization using the content below:
https://medium.com/medialesson/role-based-authorization-in-azure-functions-with-azure-ad-and-app-roles-b1fed5714c91

Using this content, does anyone know how to change my code, so it is able to handle groups, not roles? I went ahead and changed the manifest in Azure to include securitygroups. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code:

```
internal class RoleAuthorizeAttribute : FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute
{
    ...

    public override async Task OnExecutingAsync(FunctionExecutingContext executingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!executingContext.Arguments.ContainsKey("principal"))
        {
            throw new AuthorizationException("Authentication failed. Missing claims.");
        }

        var claimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)executingContext.Arguments["principal"];
        var roles = claimsPrincipal.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "roles").Select(e => e.Value);

        var isMember = roles.Intersect(_validRoles).Count() > 0;
        if (!isMember)
        {
            throw new AuthorizationException("Authentication failed. User not assigned to one of the required roles.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `claimsPrincipal.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "groups")`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the groups does not return as the group name, but instead the group id. I am not sure how to match it against the group attribute I set for my azure function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `claimsPrincipal.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "groups")` to get the groups claim.

The groups claim only returns group id rather than group name. You can loop the group ids to use Microsoft Graph to query the group names: `var group = await graphClient.Groups[{group id}"].Request().GetAsync();`. Then you could match them against the group attributes you set.

See Microsoft Graph reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request).